# Distance to closed and convex sets that have intersection $C \subseteq D \rightarrow$ $ d_D(x^*) \leq d_C(x^*) $

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, projective-geometry

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex set, and $x^* \in C^c$ (not in $C$ and its closure).

Define the Euclidean distance from $x^*$ to $C$ as $d_C(x^*):=\min_{z \in C}\|z -x^*\|_2$.

Let $D$ be a closed convex set containing $C$, i.e., $C \subseteq D$.

Show that 
$$
d_D(x^*) \leq d_C(x^*) 
$$

I do not know how to use $C \subseteq D$ together with taking minimum.

Comment: Assume the distance is strictly smaller, use minimum property and that every element in $C$ is an element in $D$. That leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C \subseteq D$, the minimum over $C$ can only be greater or equal to the minimum over $D$, so

$$d_D(x^*)=\min_{z \in D}\|z -x^*\|_2 \leq \min_{z \in C}\|z -x^*\|_2= d_D(x^*)$$

Answer (score 0):

for $\forall z \in D$ and $y\in C$, we have
\begin{align}
d_D(x^*) &= min_{z \in D} \|z-x^*\|_2 \\
&= min_{y\in C} \|(z_{best} -y)+ (y-x^*)\|_2 \\
&\leq  min_{y \in C}\|z_{best}-y\|_2 + min_{y \in C}\|y-x^*\|_2 \\
& \leq min_{y\in C}\|y-x^*\|_2 \\
&=d_C(x^*)
\end{align}

---

**Answer above has mistakes.** while, maybe we can try a new way to solve this.

Notice that for any element $y \in C$, because $C \subseteq D$, so that $y \in D$, and another element $z_{best} \in D$, satisfy $d_D(x^*)=min_{z \in D} \|z-x^*\|_2=\|z_{best}-x^*\|_2$, from this definition, it is quite clear to see
$$ \|y-x^*\|_2 \geq \|z_{best}-x^*\|_2, \forall y \in C$$
which results in
$$d_C(x^*) = min_{y\in C}\|y-x^*\|_2 \geq \|z_{best}-x^*\|_2 = d_D(x^*)$$

Comment: How do you know when you ignore $\min_{y \in C}\|z_{best}-y\|_2$ inequality still holds?

Comment: You are right! And I post a new solution under the original one. I hope it can help you.